# How to fetch an orphaned commit?

Tags: python, git, github, commit, gitpython

**tl;dr:** I have a repository cloned but cannot see an orphaned commit locally. How can I get that commit if it did not come with the repo?

**Details:**

I am trying to get the contents of a specific file on a specific commit using gitpython as below (using Git 2.17.1):

`repo.git.show('{}:{}'.format(12cf56252dcb1535e0fbeb9c3e3586551af671ea, '%s/%s' % ('versions/library-2.6' ,'Dockerfile'))` but I am getting this error:

> "Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128) cmdline: git show 12cf56252dcb1535e0fbeb9c3e3586551af671ea:versions/library-2.6/Dockerfile stderr: 'fatal: Path 'versions/library-2.6/Dockerfile' does not exist in '12cf56252dcb1535e0fbeb9c3e3586551af671ea''"

The path actually exists in that commit:
[link to the commit](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/tree/12cf56252dcb1535e0fbeb9c3e3586551af671ea)

However, a warning appears on the page saying: "This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository."

How can I get the contents of that file on this commit using gitpython?

Comment: Do you have the commit `12cf56252dcb1535e0fbeb9c3e3586551af671ea` locally? Check with `git show 12cf56252dcb1535e0fbeb9c3e3586551af671ea`

Comment: No, I have the repository cloned, how can I get that commit if it did not come with the repo? @phd

Comment: The warning seems pretty clear to me. That commit does not exist in any branch of the repository. It's not arguing that the file `versions/library-2.6/Dockerfile` doesn't exist. It's just saying that retrieving the given path from that commit is not possible since the commit doesn't exist. Where did you get that hash from?

Comment: As the commit is not on any branch sooner or later garbage collector will remove it. You better find out a commit on a branch. What are looking for? `library-2.6`? What about branch [`rootfs/library-2.6`](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/tree/rootfs/library-2.6)?

Comment: @Dan The warning on GH is clear, however, the error in the question seems to imply that the commit exists locally, but the file cannot be found in that commit.

Comment: I see you accepted my answer, however, I only knew you needed to fetch the orphaned commit from the comments. Did the error you described in the question go away after you fetched the commit locally? (If yes, I'm curious what version of Git you're using? I tested on a new version and got a different error when the commit wasn't found.)

Comment: I'm using git version 2.17.1, yes, the error went away for this specific commit. Thanks for the answer. @TTT

Comment: @smgtkn OK, great! Looks like that Git version is about 5 years old, so maybe `git show` didn't differentiate the error types back then. I'm going to update the question slightly to make it match more closely what you needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch an orphaned commit:

```
git fetch origin <full-40-char-sha>
# for example:
git fetch origin 12cf56252dcb1535e0fbeb9c3e3586551af671ea
```

This assumes the commit still exists in the repo you are fetching from (and that your remote is called `origin`). For many service based SCM tools, including GitHub and Azure DevOps, by default, pushed commits are never garbage collected and will remain reachable via their full hash, forever.

Comment: any way to fetch it by date or author? i just push force a branch and loose an ex-teammate contribution.

Comment: @rnrneverdies Where is the remote repo hosted? Many hosts offer push logs to see the history of a branch. Locally you might have luck with something like `git reflog | grep <branch-name>`

Comment: it is azure devops

Comment: @rnrneverdies you're in luck. AzDO makes it super easy because it saves every commit, branch push history, and makes it easily accessible. Under repos, selected "Pushes", and then select the branch name, and you'll see your latest push, as well as the previous commit ID it was on before your push. Then locally you can reset hard back to that commit ID and force push again to put it back (or do whatever you want with it). If you don't have the commit ID locally yet, then use this answer to get it.